# Select multiple columns having distinct just in 3 of them

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

i've got a table that i need to return about 14 column values but only return 1 row for the duplicates on some of the columns.

The second problem is that between the duplicates i need to keep the one that has the biggest int in one of the columns that is not required to be unique.

Since the Table is somewhat big, I am seeking advice into doing this in the most efficient way.

should i be doing a group by?

my table is somewhat like this, i will simplify the number of columns.

```
ID(UniqueIdentifier)                  | ACCID(UniqueIdentifier)               |   DateTime(DateTime)    | distance(int)|type(int)
28761188-0886-E911-822F-DD1FA635D450    1238FD8A-BD00-411A-A81C-0F6F5C026BCC    2019-06-03 14:04:41.000        2             3
41761188-0886-E911-822F-DD1FA635D450    1238FD8A-BD00-411A-A81C-0F6F5C026BCC    2019-06-03 14:04:41.000        1             3
```

I should be only selecting when ACCID and DATETIME is unique, the column ID in primary so will never be duplicate, and i need to keep the row with the biggest distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, as in:

```
select *
from (
  select
    id,
    accid,
    datetime,
    distance,
    type,
    row_number() over(partition by accid, datetime order by type desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

If you want to show multiple "ties", then replace `ROW_NUMBER()` by `RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a correlated subquery with the right index as the fastest method:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select top (1) t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.ACCID = t.ACCID
              order by t2.distance desc
             ) ;
```

The best index is on `(ACCID, distance desc, id)`.